# How to read JSON file using Retrofit2, RxJava2 on Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I started learning reactive programming quite recently. I can read API JSON files using Retrofit2, but I don’t know how to do it using reactive programming using RxJava2. If you have links or ready-made code, it would be grateful.
I myself tried to implement this task, but it does not work. I did everything according to this link - [https://www.learn2crack.com/2017/11/retrofit-and-rxjava-in-kotlin.html](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/11/android-rxjava-2-and-retrofit.html), but when I call the Response function in subscribe, nothing works. For example, I try to display it, but nothing is displayed.

MainActivity class

---

```
package com.example.json_rxjava

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.json_rxjava.MODEL.JsonModel
import com.example.json_rxjava.NETWORK.RequestInterface
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val BASE_URL = "https://learn2crack-json.herokuapp.com/"
    private var mCompositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable? = null
    private var mJsonModelDataList: ArrayList<JsonModel>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        loadJSON()
    }

    private fun loadJSON() {
        val requestInterface = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build().create(RequestInterface::class.java)

        mCompositeDisposable?.add( requestInterface.getData()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::handleResponse)
        )
    }

    private fun handleError(error: Throwable) {
        Log.e("ERROR: ", error.localizedMessage)
    }

    private fun handleResponse(jsonModel: List<JsonModel>) {
        Log.e("LOG TEST", "THIS IS RESPONSE")
        mJsonModelDataList = ArrayList(jsonModel)
        for(i in 0..mJsonModelDataList!!.size-1) {
            Log.e("LOG: ", mJsonModelDataList?.get(i)?.name.toString())
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mCompositeDisposable?.clear()
    }
}
```

RequestInterface

---

```
package com.example.json_rxjava.NETWORK

import com.example.json_rxjava.MODEL.JsonModel
import io.reactivex.Observable
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface RequestInterface {
    @GET("api/android")
    fun getData(): Observable<List<JsonModel>>
}
```

JsonModel

---

```
package com.example.json_rxjava.MODEL

data class JsonModel(
    val version: String,
    val name: String,
    val apiLevel: String
)
```

Added the following dependencies to build.gradle:

---

```
//RxJava and Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

In AndroidManifest added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The program outputs:

---

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa3fc0140, tid 8411
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa3fc0500, tid 8460
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xaed85360: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaed85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaed831f0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaed85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaed831f0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaed85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaed831f0)
```

Please tell me, if you know what the problem is, or if you have links or ready-made code about how to read API JSON using Retrofit2 and RxJava2 in Kotlin, then discard it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason nothing is happening is that you forgot to initialize `mCompositeDisposable`. So whenever you execute `mCompositeDisposable?.`, that code is skipped because mCompositeDisposable is `null`.

To fix it, replace the declaration with

```
private val mCompositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
```